# Global function inside in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to define a constant inside a function that could be used outside the function's scope.

```
function section {
   variable = "Hello"
}

echo variable
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its already there for you to use. try to run it and see. Remember, no spaces between "=" sign when assigning variables

```
$ function section {  variable="Hello"; }
$ section
$ echo $variable
Hello
```